# Twilio: API to see SIP status (Presence Panel / Buddy List)

Tags: twilio

I would like to be able to show in our CRM a list of all SIP Endpoints in a SIP Domain that are:

```
1. Registered
2. On a call
3. Set to DND
```

This is similar to the 'Buddy List' featured here:

https://www.twilio.com/blog/2011/09/twilio-client-presence-for-everyone.html

[image]

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I'm afraid that right now we have no API for presence on SIP endpoints.

I recommend that you get in touch with [Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) to register your interest for a feature like this. If you do, please describe your use case so that we can prioritise these features.

Thanks!

Comment: ok, thanks.  In the meantime is it possible to trigger a webhook when a SIP Endpoint is successfully registered?

Comment: I'm afraid there are not webhooks available for those events right now either.

Comment: Is there a way to make a request to a SIP endpoint to see if it's connected?

Comment: Sorry, there is not. All the API endpoints we have regarding SIP domains are available here: https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/domain

Comment: If we were to query the API for the list of all 'in-progress' calls every 10 seconds this would give us a sort-of presence panel.  Would there be a rate-limiting or cost issue from Twilio with this?  (our main use for the in-progress calls is to be able to get the SID for active calls)

Comment: Twilio's API limiting is set at [100 concurrent connections](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002943027-Understanding-Twilio-Rate-Limits-and-Message-Queues) so calling once every 10 seconds wouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Umm, yeah, I can't see why not! Good work hacking this out!

Comment: Hello! Could you do that ? The issue of this hack I can't difference between the online and offline agents. :(

Comment: @armandomiani There is currently no API to tell whether a user is registered to a SIP domain. The hack above is to make calls for the active calls to check who is currently on a call.

Answer (score 0):

I spoke with Twilio support and they hope to have an API with these features sometime in 2018.  Obviously they can't guarantee if or when, but hopefully would be soon - as this would be an awesome feature :)